# How to right align / justify bootstrap dropdown menu items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align the items within a standard bootstrap dropdown menu to the right hand side within the menu. Normally they are left aligned.

I need this because I'm displaying languages that are read Right To Left (RTL).

Nothing I try seems to work properly, using "pull-right" class on any element, e.g. the `<li>`, `<a>` or `<span>` all fail when hovering over an item - e.g. hilight is wrong size or shape.

Note that the `dropdown-menu-right` class in the `<ul>` only aligns the whole menu container with the parent button, not the items within the menu with the container (which is what I want). Code currently is:

```
   <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span dir="rtl">جديد ...</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span dir="rtl">حفظ ...</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span dir="rtl">تحميل ...</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span dir="rtl">نص عادي (العادية) المشاركة ...</span></a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="quitapp"><span dir="rtl"><i class="fa fa-close fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;الإقلاع عن التدخين ...
    </span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

(Note: I need the `<span dir="rtl">` to make sure text is displayed in the right direction, and want to keep the overall look of the menu (so not sure about converting to `<divs>` or `<listgroups>`)

Any suggestions / solutions much appreciated! I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5

Many thanks

Comment: Are you using the Bootstrap RTL CSS library?

Comment: Put li element add class text-right.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `style = "text-align : right;"` for the `a` tags. It should work.